# Behaviour of ngFor differs with trackBy index and trackBy Id when element is spliced from bounded array

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a small array of users. Now for each array element i'm adding an independent component(user-choice) which has no data binding from parent component and displays its own data.

When i remove a user at any index and use trackBy index, then the last user-choice element gets deleted instead of the one at the removed index.

But, when i use trackBy id(unique indentifier), then it works as expected.

I'm unable to understand how trackBy differs in both the cases.

Here is a demo for the same - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u4pwrl

app.component.html

```
<h1>By Id</h1>
<div *ngFor="let user of users1; let idx = index; trackBy: trackById">
  <app-user-choice></app-user-choice>
  <button (click)="deleteUser1(idx)">Delete</button>
</div>
<h1>By index</h1>
<div *ngFor="let user of users2; let idx = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">
  <app-user-choice></app-user-choice>
  <button (click)="deleteUser2(idx)">Delete</button>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  users1 = [
    {
      name: 'a',
      id: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'b',
      id: 2
    },
    {
      name: 'c',
      id: 3
    },
    {
      name: 'd',
      id: 4
    },
    {
      name: 'e',
      id: 5
    }
  ];
  users2 = [
    {
      name: 'a',
      id: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'b',
      id: 2
    },
    {
      name: 'c',
      id: 3
    },
    {
      name: 'd',
      id: 4
    },
    {
      name: 'e',
      id: 5
    }
  ];
  num = 0;
  deleteUser1(idx) {
    this.users1.splice(idx, 1);
  }
  deleteUser2(idx) {
    this.users2.splice(idx, 1);
  }
  trackById(index, item) {
    return item.id;
  }
  trackByIndex(index) {
    return index;
  }
}
```

user-choice.component.html

```
<p>
  user-info works! {{index}}
</p>
```

user-choice.component.ts

```
export class UserChoiceComponent implements OnInit {
  index = Math.random() * 10;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: What value do you get inside `trackByIndex(index) { return index; }` when you add a `console.log(index);`

Comment: @Lynx242..based on the length..if length is 4 - 0,1,2,3..and on each delete...0,1,2...0,1 and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`trackBy` is supposed to prevent Angular from tracking all changes in an iterable when there is only exactly one change expected.

The main problem is, that your `(click)` directive gets fired before track by comes into play. You click the delete button, the item gets removed and then `trackBy` checks for changes.

With`trackById()`-method you always return the actual `id` of the object which has been deleted. You click, e.g., the object with `id` 3 and `trackById` returns 3. So Angular can detect the changed object and removes it properly from the UI.

`trackByIndex()` returns Angular's own index from the loop. Now imagine you have a list of objects with `id`s from 0 to 4. Only at start the index of Angular and the id of the object match. And now you delete one object. Let's say the object with `id` 3. Then there is no `id` 3 among the objects any more, but Angular still monitors the object with `index` 3. Moreover, the objects at index 0 to 2 have an id 0 to 2 but the object at index 3 has the id 4, because the indexing gets always adjusted according to the order of entries.

Angular does not know which object actually changed as it monitores the wrong item. And thus is uses default behavior and removes the last entry from the list. This is why the `byIndex` approach does not work at all here.

---

***An example***

**START**

```
name:       a
Angular id: 0
object id:  0

name:       b
Angular id: 1
object id:  1

name:       c
Angular id: 2
object id:  2

name:       d
Angular id: 3
object id:  3

name:       e
Angular id: 4
object id:  4
```

**Now you click `delete` at object with id 3.**

When you do this. The item gets removed from the list first and only then `trackBy` starts working. But There is no object with `id` 3 any more.

```
name:       a
Angular id: 0
object id:  0

name:       b
Angular id: 1
object id:  1

name:       c
Angular id: 2
object id:  2

name:       e
Angular id: 3
object id:  4
```

You see. The main problem is, that using the static ordered index of Angular's can't work here as the object's index will never match. You have to use the object's own id.

Comment: Please, be so kind and mark this explanation as solution, if it answers your question.

Comment: but suppose inside the for loop I have a p element which has [innerHtml]="name" - so when I track by index and delete suppose the one with id 3..so the p tag element displays the right data but the last app-user-choice gets deleted

Comment: Alia, it is all about the fact that you have 2 unequal indexes running around. **trackById** uses the matching index as you return the **own id** of the object and you remove this object searching it by its own id. **trackByIndex** uses the/a non matching index as you return the index Angular provides from the loop. Angulars index is always one lower than the actual id of the object. I extended my answer. Please, have a look at it.

Comment: as you mentioned if i change my id to start from 0 then trackByIndex would work properly..but it doesn't..i have updated the stackblitz code...still last item is only getting deleted

Comment: Okay. You were right. My train of thoughts went slightly wrong. But still it is a matter of fact, that using the index of Angular's and comparing it against the `id` of the objects can't work. This is because `(click)` is fired first and the list is already missing the deleted object before `trackBy` comes into play. I adjusted my explanation above. --- My recommendation is: use `trackById`. It is proper for your use case.